# how to check network connection status in libgdx with robovm?

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm

according to this website
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

I know how to add a admob banner in a libgdx game through robovm, and that worked!

Everything works fine when my Iphone is connected to either wifi or grps. However when I turn off wifi and grps, the game would quit immediately after the splash screen. This is because the `initializeAds` function  is not connected to either wifi or gprs.

In OBJC there is a file named `connection.h` to check whether gprs or wifi is connected. After that, we can initialize admob banner according to the status.

Is there a way to check connection status by `robovm` or is there a way to avoid the crash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write simple function on Java, which will ping google.com and return true/false. Use this to send the request:

```
Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest(HttpRequest httpRequest, HttpResponseListener httpResponseListener);
```

Than check in you `httpResponseListener` if you got the respond (there is internet connection) if it will have the error (there is not).

P.S For Android add this to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Is this still applycable? Is my server IP eligible to a Goggle ban?